# How can I insert an ironpython console into my form?

Tags: c#, winforms, ironpython, interactive

I want to make a winform by C#, and add a ironpython console window in it, like a multiline textbox.
So I can write python program into it to do some operations in my Winform software.

How can I do that?
Thanks.

affixture:

I created a opensource project IpyIF, Ironpython Interactive Window.http://ipyiw.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot.
I got it by myself.

I use two TextBox, one is to input code of ironpython, another is to redirect the ironpython output.

If someone want to know how to redirection, look this:
[How can I redirect the stdout of IronPython in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3055002/how-can-i-redirect-the-stdout-of-ironpython-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

maybe you could [start here](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/ironpython/dlr_hosting.shtml).

Quickstart: You need a string with your code from your textbox in "script".
Add references from IronPython, IronPython.Modules, Microsoft.Scripting and Microsoft.Scripting.Core to your project.

```
ScriptRuntime runtime = IronPython.Hosting.Python.CreateRuntime();
ScriptScope scope = runtime.GetEngine("py").CreateScope();
ScriptSource source = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString(script,
                                  Microsoft.Scripting.SourceCodeKind.Statements);
source.Execute(scope);
```

a **real console** is included in the [CodePlex-Samples](http://ironpython.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/68511#992778)

Comment: I known this to call ironpython file/code/string.

I want to realize the interative window.
In it, I can write a line, and dir() the objects,
and wirte another ...

Comment: Yes,like trypython.
But I want a simple realization in Winform.
Where can I find the code?

Comment: I check out the code of trypython, and I found it work with sliverlight. So I doesn't know how or can it add in WinForm.