# IronPython scripts execution from C# code

Tags: c#, dynamic, ironpython

I have one question, I have such code

```
this._engine = Python.CreateEngine();
ScriptSource source = this._engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString(script.SourceCode);
ScriptScope scope = this._engine.CreateScope();
ObjectOperations operations = this._engine.Operations;
source.Execute(scope);
```

And I am trying to execute IronPython code from tutorial:

```
from System.Collections import BitArray
ba = BitArray(5)
ba.Set(0, True) # call the Set method
print ba[0]
```

So it executes correctly, but I can't understand if i have `print ba[0]` why it doesn't output this value to the console? By the way, could you advice some good articles about using IronPython for applications scripting?

And another question is if I have some Python class and I do not know the name of this class, because the client can define it manually, is it possible to create an instance of this class? For example

```
class SomeClass(object):
    def some(self, a, b):
        return <something>
```

Now I'm trying to use this code

```
dynamic SomeClass = scope.GetVariable("SomeClass");
dynamic something = SomeClass();
something.some(x,y);
```

Should I iterate through `ScriptScope.GetItems()` collection and search for `PythonType` objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to call:

```
this._engine.Runtime.IO.RedirectToConsole();
```

Otherwise have a look [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3055002/how-can-i-redirect-the-stdout-of-ironpython-in-c) for a similar question about redirecting.

About python class instantiation in C#, your code seems to be ok, as shown in this [**question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579272/instantiating-a-python-class-in-c) (look at the 3rd answer)

**EDIT:**

Sorry I didn't read your question with enough attention...

Anyway, to look for available classes in Python, just do as you said,

i.e. something like:

```
var availDynClasses = items.Where(x => x.Value is IronPython.Runtime.Types.PythonType);
```

Comment: Ok, thanks! I don't really understand with instantiation, it works OK when I exactly know what is the class name. But if clients define their own custom class with some custom name, which implements some interface (for example with one method Do()) and I want to instantiate this class and run this Do() method, but I can't use 'scope.GetVariable()', because I don't know the class name.